# Select from a big table with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, myisam

I need to get top 30 ips for a period (month here) with maximum sum of bytes.

```
SELECT SUM(bytes) as bytes,  ip  
            FROM table
            WHERE stamp_inserted >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00'
            GROUP BY ip
            ORDER BY bytes DESC
            LIMIT 30
```

Table has 10 000 000+ records (will grow).
Type is  myisam.

I tryed to add indexes for bytes, ip, stamp_insered. And one index for all (complex index?).

Explain says:

> type: range
> key: stamp_inserted (complex index)
> rows: 6988465
> extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

It takes 15 seconds. If i remove ORDER - 10 seconds.
Is this normal? Or how can i make it faster?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `all` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `bytes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stamp_inserted` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip_dst`),
  KEY `bytes` (`bytes`),
  KEY `stamp_inserted` (`stamp_inserted`),
  KEY `bytes_2` (`bytes`,`ip`,`stamp_inserted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11218827 ;
```

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: ip_dst char(15)
bytes bigint(20) 
stamp_inserted datetime

Comment: You are not honest :-) you must have `ip` column in your table. And when I ask to post, I mean post it into your original post :-) so everybody can see that. and try to get full `CREATE TABLE` statement from your database.

Comment: Yes, i posted it into the main post

Comment: you're not going to be able to avoid filesort on that query because you're sorting by the aggregate value

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Could you explain deeper your goal please? the only way improve performance is to improve your query. As @pala_ said you can do nothing with this type of order. IMHO you have enough indexes. but query could be improved. Just need to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @АртемКостерев [look here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50224/index-for-order-by-on-aggregate-in-mysql). it might help you understand. an index on `(stamp_inserted, ip)` is likely the best you can do - your current covering key is insufficient - the order of the values matters, and it should have the field used in your where clause first, then that in your group by

Comment: are you trying to build billing system? you are really counting bytes? if so - I would suggest modify database structure to improve performance. you can create another table with aggregated `sum(bytes)` and create trigger on your table to update that value every time you update `all` table

Comment: yes, i guess only aggregation can help me here, just wanted anyone else say me that :)